# Нужен пример работы html

Tags: html, python, url

С новостного сайта мне нужно взять статью и выписать ее. Каждый раз я беру рандомный ip и каждый раз получаю разную информацию. Но есть ошибка, потому что получается с сервера не JSON, а HTML. Так вот это исправить и если можно пример.

```
import json
from urllib.request import urlopen
from webbrowser import open_new


url = 'http://fakty.ictv.ua/ru/index/read-news/id/1571335'
data = urlopen(url).read().decode('utf8')
data = json.loads(data)
print(data)
```

Comment: А сервер должен отдавать JSON по этой ссылке? Вы уверены?

Comment: Нет я уже понял что там html. НО как сделать это с ним не понимаю.

Comment: НИКАК. Потому что JSON - не HTML. О чем вам ранее уже писали.

Comment: вопрос слишком общий: излагать что такое html и как с ним работать -- это тема для небольшой книги, а не одного ответа. Конкретизируйте ваш вопрос -- в чём именно проблема? (понимаете ли вы слово таг, динамический контент, cookies?)

Answer (score 1):

Используйте парсер HTML. Для питона их есть много разных. Гуглится по "python parse html" - выбирайте, что больше нравится. Благо, примеров к ним тоже валом.

Можно использовать регулярки, если разметка сайта позволяет написать не особо головоломное правило.

Только учтите, что если ваш источник поменяет разметку страницы, ваш скрипт может сломаться.